# K2 Add tag to article if the keyword is in the article title

Tags: mysql, tags, k2

This seems to be a bit out of my league and knowledge of MySQL. So if someone can help it would be much appreciated.

I would like to do the following:

1. Enter/define a keyword e.g. `mercedes`
2. Find all K2 articles that have that keyword in the title
3. Than to each of those articles assign my keyword `mercedes` as a tag.

Now... There are three tables with relevant columns listed:

#### k2_items

`id`, `title`

#### k2_tags

`id`, `name`, `published` (value 1 is assigned if tag is published)

#### k2_tags_xref

`id`, `tagID`, `itemID`

So, query should select all items from `k2_items` table that have `keyword` in their title, check if `keyword` is already defined as `tag` in `k2_tags`, if not than create a new tag. After that, new `k2_tags_xref` entry should be generated to connect `keyword` tag with K2 article item.

I still didn't have database course on my university so I'm kind of out of my league with this one, and it was supposed to be just a simple touchup for the site I'm developing.

Any help with this would be much appreciated, and I'm sure it'll help community later on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of queries that you need to execute. **Please use these queries first on a test environment.** There is an idea:

```
/* Query 1: Select the id of the tag */ 
SELECT id FROM `#__k2_tags` WHERE `name` = 'mercedes' LIMIT 1;

/* Query 2: If previous query returned null, create a new tag */
INSERT INTO `#__k2_tags`
SET `name` = 'mercedes',
`published` = 1;

/* Query 3: Use this to get the last id or use id from Query 1 */
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();

/* Query 4: Insert tags for each article that contains in the title the word mercedes */
INSERT INTO `#__k2_tags_xref` (`tagID`,`itemID`)
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 'YOUR_TAG_ID', i.id
    FROM `#__k2_items` AS i
    WHERE LOCATE('mercedes', title) > 0
)
```

Comment: Why do you use DISTINCT in the subquery?  Is the  table alias necessary? I thought not.  Also, `> 0` can be removed.  If `name` in `#__k2_tags` is declared as a UNIQUE KEY then `LIMIT 1` can be omitted.  It might be good to mention UNIQUE KEYS in the schemas.